# Using a CMFCStatusBar in a CDialogEX project

Tags: mfc

Why is it that I can use a `CStatusBar` in a `CDialogEx` file but not a `CMFCStatusBar`? When I change the variable type and run it I get a exception about an invalid property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status bar like other bars and views may only reside in a Frame window.

A bunch of internal code uses `GetParentFrame`. And this function only returns a pointer of the next outer `CFrameWnd`.

There are tricks (I never used them) on [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2685/Toolbar-StatusBar-on-Dialog) to embed toolbars into a dialog. But I am not sure that they will work with the new CMFC... stuff.

Comment: No worries then, I will stick with `CStatusBar` as it is simple. I was just hopign to make use of the `SetBitmap` method. The older status bar only accepts `SetIcon`.

Comment: BTW: If this is a dialog based application it is much easier to use a normal `CFrameWnd` and a `CFormView` inside instead of a dialog based application. In this case you don't need any hack.

Comment: This is a popup editor inside a main dialog application. And I akready have translations for the resources in over 40 languages which i would have to migrate. It isn't worth doing that. But thanks for the suggestion